# notify-send doesn't work from script but works from terminal

Tags: shell, command-line, notifications

I am trying to run this script:
`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash  
BAT_LEVEL=`acpi -b |grep -Eo "[0-9]+%"|grep -Eo "[0-9]+"`
CRIT=0                                                           
if [ $BAT_LEVEL -gt $CRIT ]; then
    echo "foo"
    aplay ~/apert.wav
    notify-send "Battery-Low"
    echo "bar"
fi
```

The sixth line from above which is `notify-send "Battery-Low"` works just as you'd expect in terminal.
But when the script is executed it just spits out `foo` and `bar` on stdout.
I have no clue what the problem might be.

Comment: Are you invoking this script at a shell prompt? If not, how?

Comment: I made the file executable. and all I'm doing is `./test.sh` in the directory of the file inside `M-x shell` of emacs.

Comment: Well, that had me thinking. Turns out the script runs just fine from terminal emulator. I can't see why it shouldn't work from inside of emacs shell! Also the `aplay` line gives me some error too.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing some environment variables, most likely the `DISPLAY` one. You could try the following:

```
echo "foo"                                                   
DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send "Battery-Low"                                    
echo "bar"
```

If that doesn't help, you could compare the environment inside the script and in a terminal by running the `env` command in both.

Also note that if the script is being run as root, you may have to do something like this:

```
sudo -u yourUsername DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send 'Battery low'
```

Comment: I was indeed running the script as root. But the notification still doesn't appear when I do `sudo -u bibek DISPLAY=0.0 notify-send "battery-low"`. It doesn't give me any error either.

Comment: @coder_Bibek You also need to set the variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to what it is in your normal session. We can give more guidance if you explain how you run the script, what you've said about that so far is strange (as root *and* inside Emacs? are you running Emacs as root?).

Comment: Note that there should be a `:` before the `0.0` for it to work. But yes, notify-send needs the session bus as well, and I can't think of a clean way to get it... Check with `env` to see if it's set?

Comment: `env | grep DBUS` give me same output `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` on both the shells as root and as user `bibek`.  And yes, I am running emacs as root with `sudo emacs &` from the terminal emulator. (Accessing root files with normal emacs session is painful, at best; and I'ven't given other methods a try yet.)